# How can I set a minimum amount of space between flexbox items?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Given this CSS:

```css
div.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
div.container div {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

This layout has the first item in each row aligned to the left, and the last item aligned to the right, as required.

As the browser window is made narrower, the distributed `div` elements will move closer together until they **touch**, at which point they are re-arranged over an additional row. Again, the first div on each row is aligned left, and the last aligned right with space between.

Is there any way of setting a **minimum spacing** so that the inner `div` elements always have a gap between them.

*padding and margin will probably not work*, as the alignment

`<-- 1st left in row` and `last right in row -->` will not hold.

Comment: Possibly fastest way: _.container_ `margin-right: -10px` _.container div_ `margin-right: 10px`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can add another div with flex style for holding the needed gap between inner divs. and for the minimum width for that gap use this property (as mentioned in W3Schools.com):

> flex: flex-grow flex-shrink flex-basis|auto|initial|inherit;

which flex-shrink is :

> flex-shrink:  A number specifying how much the item will shrink relative to the rest of the flexible items

so, for example you set this css code for the gap div :

```
flex: 1 0 10px;
```

that tells gap div will have 10px width, and will grow relative to the rest of the flexible items, but WON'T SHRINK. so the minimum width will be 10px at the narrowest width of the screen.

Comment: I don't think what I want to do is possible. I tried your [suggestion](http://codepen.io/jimmymain/pen/QjvZoN), but this results in a gap div on the right when the browser window is narrow, and the alignment of the last item in each row is no longer on the right.

Comment: if you wanna have the first div on the left, and last one on the right, you have to make it responsive by turning your flex widths to percent values, and also `  flex-flow: row nowrap;` to hold all the elements in one row.

Answer (score 43):

Bit late the the party but I ran into the same issue. The way I solved it probably wont work for everyone but here it is for those who can use it.

The basic idea is that you have a min gap of `x`. You set the left and right margins of each item to `x/2` so that the distance between the items will be `x` (margin + margin). Then you wrap all of the items in a container with a left and right margin of `-x/2`. This will hide the margin on the items at the edges of each row.

Here is a working example:

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 -1em;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `overflow-x: hidden;` on `.box` is to prevent the horizontal scrollbar that shows up in some browsers because of the margin overflowing.

If you want the gap to always be consistent and for rows with only one item to have that item span the whole row then you can add `flex-grow: 1` to `.item`.

Comment: I would set `.item:nth-child(n+2){margin-left:2em}` to avoid the negative margins of the container and halving the spacing

Comment: @venimus This should be an answer, not a comment. It's perfect.

Comment: @Darkproduct the objective was to allow for reflow (dynamic number of elements on each row based on available space). If you open my example in a larger window then you will see more items on the first "row". I believe that specifying an nth child would only work if you knew the number of items in each "row".

Answer (score 29):

In 2022 you can just use `gap` CSS property:

```css
div.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  gap: 20px;
}
```

To support older browsers you may use [margin hack](https://coryrylan.com/blog/css-gap-space-with-flexbox).

```css
div.container > * {
  margin: 12px 0 0 12px;
}

div.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: -12px 0 0 -12px;
  width: calc(100% + 12px);
}
```

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer atm, and this is a perfect example of the fact that you shouldn't just look at the first answer in this portal, but scroll down to see more, because there might be pearls like this one hidden.

Comment: Gap seems to mess up the spacing under justify-content:space-evenly. It makes sure there is a minimum width gap inside, but not at the edges. Also, there seems to be no way to specify a maximum gap that should not be made wider.

Comment: The issue with this is the gap is added alongside the space created with justify-content. I want to set a "minimum-gap" without affecting the usual gap, and to add a "max-gap" would be useful too. Maybe, CSS4?

Comment: Wow awesome! This has been annoying me a long time! `justify-content: flex-start; gap: 10px;` works wonders

Answer (score 7):

Since April 2021 support for [`flexbox-gap`](https://caniuse.com/flexbox-gap) has arrived in all major browsers (IE considered [dead](https://death-to-ie11.com/)). Combining it w/ `space-between` solves your problem.

```css
div.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px; /* minimum gap between flex-items */
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: justify-content:space-between can sometimes leave a lot of space in the middle (inside) but very little space at the edges (outside). justify-content:space-evenly looks much better for most cases, but gap can't be used.

Answer (score 2):

It's a couple of days passed since this question was asked, but I thought I should add my solution if anybody comes past and has the same issue.

I suggest using calc, width, and media to solve this issue. Yes, it's a little work but it's a visual clean solution in my opinion.

```css
.main{
  display:         flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap:       wrap;
}
.main > div{
  width: 100%;
  height: 125px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .main > div{
    width: calc(100% / 2 - 5px);
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .main > div{
    width: calc(100% / 3 - 5px);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1140px) {
  .main > div{
    width: calc(100% / 6 - 5px);
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

For the needed breakpoints I calculate the width I want the divs to use and subtract the space I want them to have.

I hope this helps someone and that I explained it understandable.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a flex-basis with percentage also will do the trick. Then the min space between will be also in percentage. 
For instance, with 3 elements, flex: 0 0 30% will allow a fixed 10% space reparted between elements.
with 6 elements, flex: 0 0 15% and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I would set

`.item:nth-child(n+2){margin-left:2em}`

to avoid the negative margins of the container and halving the spacing

Comment: not my own comment / answer, but it works and is the simplest solution on this page. Posting as an answer for visibility